# Comparison of N Strings of size M with K Substring of size L

Tags: python, algorithm

```
    Strings:
    "Today is a good day, I would like to go to supermarket for an errand. I would be able to cook for my husband tonight."
    "Today is a rainy day, I would like to go for an errand. Jason would like to cook for me tonight."
    "Yesterday is a good day, I would like to go to Cosco for an errand. I will like to cook for my family tonight."
    "I would like to go to Lawson for an errand. I will try to cook for your family tonight."
    "Today is a good day, she goes to supermarket for an errand. She cook for me tonight."

    Substrings:
    "Today is a good day"
    "I would like to"
    "for my family"
```

As we can see there are N = 5 strings and each has at most M = 21 words while there are K = 3 substrings and each has at most L = 6 words. I want to get the following information in the comparison:

1. Which strings do not contain the particular substring or contain the substring with “typo”
   (eg. "I would like to" : 3 strings, 2nd and 4th are with typo, 5th  is with 0 found)
2. Find the existing substring which is similar to the given substring, percentage of similarity and the percentage of occurrence, which string
   (eg. "I would like to" ->
   a. "I would like to": (similarity: 100%),(Occurrence:4/8=50%), (String: all except last)
   b. "I would be able to": (similarity: 3/4=75%),(Occurrence:1/8=12.5%), (String: 1)
   c. "Jason would like to": (similarity: 3/4=75%),(Occurrence:1/8=12.5%), (String: 2)
   d. "I will like to": (similarity: 3/4=75%),(Occurrence:1/8=12.5%), (String: 3)
   e. "I will try to": (similarity: 2/4=50%),(Occurrence:1/8=12.5%)), (String: 4)

Solution I have think of:

1. For each string, compare it with each substring word by word but the worst run time will be N*M*K*L
2. Turn strings into a dictionary tree, each node contains the word and the number of strings at that node, by traversing down the tree and compare each substring word by word, the run time will be N to form the tree + M*K*L but the starting point varies (4th string has no "Today .... day,") and missing part in some string("to supermarket is not found in 2nd string). Secondly, unable to track which strings have 0 found or with “typo”

Seem like the first solution will be the most ideal solution but it takes longer time if the number of N increases. Is there any better solution to this question?

Comment: Does typos mean mistyped characters only or does it also mean characters are missing/added ?

Comment: "typo" is a word I use to explain the different words existing among the substring. For example, "will" in string 3 is the different word compared to the "I would like to".

Comment: I think you should change the word "typo" with something else as that word already have another meaning.

Answer (score 0):

In python most solutions seems to work better with hashmap.

Concept pseudo code

```
use a hashmap to convert words to numbers // avoids further factor P for word length
make dict from wordnumber to list of occurances in strings, position in strings

convert substrings to numbers

for substring in substrings // O(K)
  for subword in substring // O(L) - not used in pt. 1.
    for curr in dict[subword] // O(Q) occurrances of word in all strings
      for word in strings[curr.stringNo][cur.position-subword.position...cur.position+substringlength-1-subword.position] // O(L)
        compare with substring // O(1), for pt.1. actually we can start from the next position as we already know the first is a match.
          count match // O(1) or break in case of pt.1. lowering the L to the actual match number.
```

- pt. 1 : QKL   vs NMKL
- pt. 2 : QKL^2 vs NMKL^2

So is Q < NM? If all strings consists of only 'I's they are equal, in most cases Q would be an order or two of magnitude less than NM but at the cost of en hashmap lookup. So on average the Q solution would be better in worst case the same.

If you don't translate to numbers all solutions needs an extra factor P word length.

The extra L for partial match is because you will need to check for each word in the substring to find a partial match.